# How to format tailwind classes in netlify classname template literals

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

i used a package called `netlify classname template literals`

```
  const styles = ctl(`
    text-gray-400
    transition-all
    hover:text-black
    duration-500 
    hover:bg-red-600`
);
```

i want to sort the classes automatic in the code
like in `Headwind` extension but the extension only works in `className=""`